# Вложенные циклы в интерпретаторе brainf*ck

Tags: c, компилятор, brainfuck

Здравствуйте, пишу интерпретатор BrainFuck на Си, и столкнулся с проблемой интерпретирования вложенных циклов, но никак не получилось найти решение этой проблемы, может кто подскажет как это могло бы выглядеть на си? 
p.s. видел схожий вопрос на c++, но синтаксиса c++ не знаю вообще и почти не понимаю.

пример кода

```brainfuck
    >++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<.>>+>+>++>[-]+<[>[->+<<++++>]<<]>.+++++++..+++.>>+++++++.<<<<+++++++++++++.>>.+++.------.————.>>+.>++++.
```

Я хотел при нахождение вложенного цикла, скопировать его, и отправить на компиляцию только его, потом вернуться в исходную программу, но наверно у меня где то есть ошибки в коде, которые я не могу найти, возможно есть более просто решение:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
#include < string.h >

int interpreter_function(char*, char*, int*, int*);

int main(void)
{
    char str_output[30000];
    memset(str_output,0,sizeof(str_output));
    int i;
    int position=0;
    int count=0;
    char programm[]=">++++++++[<+++++++++>-]<.>>+>+>++>[-]+<[>[->+<<++++>]<<]>.+++++++..+++.>>+++++++.<<<<+++++++++++++.>>.+++.------.————.>>+.>++++.";
    for (i=0;programm[i]!='\0';i++)        // number of characters
        count++;

    interpreter_function( str_output,programm, &position, &count);
    return 0;
}

int interpreter_function(char *str_output, char *programm,int *pi_position, int *pi_count)
{
    int i,k,j,z,d=0;
    int symbol_count=0;
    int transfer_count=1,transfer_position=0;
    int array_counter_1=0, control=1,array_counter_2=1;

    for (i=0;i<*pi_count;i++)
    {
     switch (programm[i])
        {
            case '+' : str_output[*pi_position]++;
                break;

            case '-' : str_output[*pi_position]--;
                break;

            case '>' : (*pi_position)++;
                break;

            case '.': printf("%c",str_output[*pi_position]);
                break;


            case '<' : (*pi_position)--;
                break;

            case '[' :
            {
                for (k=i;programm[k]!=']' && array_counter_1!=control;k++)
                {
                    symbol_count++;

                    if (programm[k+1]=='[')
                    {
                        control++;
                        for (j=k+1;programm[j]!=']';j++)
                            transfer_count++;

                        char transfer_function[transfer_count+1];

                        for (z=k+1;z<=k+transfer_count;z++)
                        {
                            transfer_function[d]=programm[z];
                            d++;
                        }

                        transfer_position=k+1;
                        interpreter_function(str_output,transfer_function, pi_position, &transfer_count);
                    }
                    if (programm[k]==']')
                        array_counter_1++;
                }
            }
                break;

            case ']':
                if(array_counter_2==control)
                {
                    {
                        i=i-symbol_count;
                        if (str_output[*pi_position]==0)              // if the count of cycle = 0, go forward to the end of cycle
                        {
                            i=i+symbol_count;
                            symbol_count=0;
                        }
                        control=1;
                        array_counter_2=1;
                        array_counter_1=0;
                    }
                }
                else
                    array_counter_2++;
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, вы должны, увидев `[`, сделать следующее:

- если байт по текущему указателю **не ноль**, перейти к следующей инструкции
- иначе пройти вперёд по списку команд, не выполняя их, чтобы пропустить текущий цикл, для этого

  - установите счётчик в 1
  - продвигайтесь вперёд; если встретите `[`, увеличивайте счётчик; если встретите `]`, уменьшайте счётчик, и переходите к следующей команде
  - когда счётчик станет равным нулю, остановитесь
  - продвиньтесь ещё на одну инструкцию (это будет следующая за парным `]`) и продолжайте интерпретацию
  - если в процессе поиска счётчик не достиг нуля, а текст программы закончился, остановите интерпретацию с ошибкой

Аналогично, увидев `]`, вы должны сделать следующее:

- если байт по текущему указателю **ноль**, перейти к следующей инструкции
- иначе пройти назад по списку команд до парной `]`, не выполняя их, для этого

  - установите счётчик в 1
  - продвигайтесь назад; если встретите `]`, увеличивайте счётчик; если встретите `[`, уменьшайте счётчик, и переходите к предыдущей команде
  - когда счётчик станет равным нулю, остановитесь
  - продвиньтесь на одну инструкцию вперёд (это будет следующая за парным `[`) и продолжайте интерпретацию
  - если в процессе поиска счётчик не достиг нуля, а текст программы закончился, остановите интерпретацию с ошибкой

Источник: [Википедия](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Commands).

---

Компиляция в C этом смысле была бы проще, поиск конца цикла и обработка вложенности при этом переложилась бы на внешний компилятор.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я добавил код на си, который у меня есть, правда он не рабочий . Но на сколько я понимаю, при встрече крайнего ']' он не должен пошагово возвращаться назад, так как в таком случае он будет выполнять все эти команды. Наверно он должен перекидывать положение на начало цикла сразу?

Comment: @AntonBarinov: Угу, он должен возвращаться, не выполняя команды по дороге.